# Required com.google.android.gms.GoogleMap found void

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I have looked online to find a solution as getMap() method is Deprecated, therefore, I would like to replace it with getMapAsync();. I have searched on google as well as androids official documentations and I am still stuck please help.

I am now getting one error message which says incompatible type 
Required com.google.android.gms.GoogleMap found void.

```
public class Maps extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Maps);

        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.mapFragment)).getMapAsync(this);


        LatLng latlong = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlong).title(name));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlong, 15));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }
}
```

**This method below gives the error and it says incompatible type 
Required com.google.android.gms.GoogleMap found void.**

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.mapFragment)).getMapAsync(this);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getMapAsync` has as return type void, and you are trying to assign it

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.mapFragment)).getMapAsync(this);
```

to `googleMap`. Which doesn't make much sense. Call only `getMapAsync` like

```
((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.mapFragment)).getMapAsync(this);
```

and assign `googleMap` when `onMapReady` is invoked. E.g.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
}
```